# Create my own intermediate cetification authority from commonly trusted certificate

Tags: ssl, certificate, signing, pki, certificate-authority

I have a simple question (maybe stupid) and i didn't find any clear answer to it. If i get a certificate from a trusted signing company (like verisign...) for one of my server (web for instance), i'll have private an public keys. With this certificate can i set up my own intermediate CA and sign cert request and the be trusted by every one (i know that's shouldn't be..)? My real question is : what will prevent me for  issuing certificate and how the company can garanty that nobody does ??

Thanking in advance!

Answer (score 1):

The certificate issued for your web site is suitable for SSL/TLS and is not suitable for issuing other certificates (Key Usage field is different). Consequently while you technically can generate another certificate using yours as a CA, such generated certificate won't be trusted by properly implemented and configured validators (those that check Key Usage).

Comment: Thanks a lot! Is there a particular certification/standard to ensure that a client/validator read this "Key Usage" extention ?

Comment: @user2216188, [RFC 5280](http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc5280) (or 3280) is probably the spec you're looking for. To be a CA cert, it's not just about key usage, but "basic constraints" too.

Answer (score 0):

You are not paying verisign or other certificate organisation for the certificate publishing but for the certificate validation, this meens that they have web services that respond if your certificate is valid or not, if it is still active and not expired and your contact information as requested.

Unfortunatly this is something you have to live with it and pay them if you really need ssl over your site.

I have used a homemade certificate for my lan server and when i visit this https site a big red warning notifies me that this site is malicious and it has not a valid certificate. This doesn't bother me but I am sure that all of my clients would have freeked out if they see such a bold warning popping up to their browser.

what can you do? it's a companies' world